# How to count all rows on Hbase table using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hbase, nosql-aggregation, nosql

we can count all rows, using **hbase shell** with this command : `count 'table_name', INTERVAL=> 1` or just simple `count 'table_name`.

But How to do this using **Scala Programming** ?

Comment: you can use the java client

Comment: here is an example to achieve that using Java Programming, https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mogujie/mst/hbase/mapreduce/RowCounterTest.java, maybe it will give you some hints

Comment: I would argue that the answer depends a lot on what client you use.
There is the standard Java Client, Scalding and HPaste specifically for using HBase from Scala. Then there is asynchbase... In order to give you an answer, some information on which client you are using would be useful.

Comment: please see my answer I gave the pointer to do it in scala. Although, its a very rare practice!

Comment: @RamPrasadG i will try today and give you news about my experiment.. thanks

Comment: any news on this it worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have done with java client for Hbase,  I researched and found out the below..
***Java way code snippet :***

You can use [***KeyOnlyFilter***](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/KeyOnlyFilter.html)() to get only Keys of the rows. and then loop like below..

```
   for (Result rs = scanner.next(); rs != null; rs = scanner.next()) {
        number++;
    }
```

like above you can use the below scala hbase example..

[Please look at the Java API. Adaptation to scala should be relatively easy. The example below shows part of the sample Java code adapted to scala:](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Scala)

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes


val conf = new HBaseConfiguration()
val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)

// list the tables
val listtables=admin.listTables() 
listtables.foreach(println)

// let's insert some data in 'mytable' and get the row

val table = new HTable(conf, "mytable")

val theput= new Put(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey1"))

theput.add(Bytes.toBytes("ids"),Bytes.toBytes("id1"),Bytes.toBytes("one"))
table.put(theput)

val theget= new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey1"))
val result=table.get(theget)
val value=result.value()
println(Bytes.toString(value))
```

> However as an additional information(and best way than java or scala) please see below

`RowCounter` is a mapreduce job to count all the rows of a table. This is a good utility to use as a sanity check to ensure that `HBase` can read all the blocks of a table if there are any concerns of metadata inconsistency. It will run the mapreduce all in a single process but it will run faster if you have a MapReduce cluster in place for it to exploit.

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter <tablename>

Usage: RowCounter [options] 
    <tablename> [          
        --starttime=[start] 
        --endtime=[end] 
        [--range=[startKey],[endKey]] 
        [<column1> <column2>...]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With java client, you can scan all table with RowKeyOnlyFilter is effective. By this way you only transfer rowkeys to your client code, not data, so it will be faster. This is what count 'tablename' does in shell too.